# 2sxc Blog : How to change social media icons

Tags: 2sxc

How to restrict non-admin users from making any kind of modifications to blog content, post or remove blog?

How to change the images for social media icons in blog list item? There are in build images for social media.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Blog App 3.03 uses AddThis. See App.Settings. You need to go setup an account on AddThis, then get the URL with your 'key' saved in the settings. Then you configure things on the AddThis site for your project; which shares to include.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow :)

@Accuraty-Jeremy is right - as of now, it just uses AddThis. You can try to customize that, or create your own share-feature as you want, since the html-source is there, ready for editing.